# Remove non-duplicate records based on date in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have data structured like this:
[sample patient data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tea7N.png)

Basically, it's a list of patients who have received a pair of blood tests (A, B) on a certain date BUT they could've been given 1 of those blood tests separately on another date (and many of them were), and those records are all mixed in together, so the data I have are like:

```
test_date patient# test_type result
20191001        1      A        77
20191001        2      A        34
20191001        2      B        66
...            ...    ...      ...
20191011        15     A        111
20191011        15     B        222
20191011        1      A        32
20191011        1      B        99
```

I have been working in python (pandas, numpy) to clean the data up to this point, and now I'm trying to remove the non-duplicate patient# records by date (remove rows of patients who only received one test on a given date), because I want to compare the test results (A, B) ONLY for patients who received BOTH tests on the SAME date.

The big caveat here is that, for example, patient #1 could've received ONLY Test A on 2019-10-01 but did receive BOTH Tests A & B on 2019-10-02 and/or some other dates (1 patient could've received both tests on multiple dates). So in that example I would want to discard patient #1's 2019-10-01 test record but preserve the 2019-10-02 one (and any later pairs).

Ideally, my finalized data would look something like this:
[cleaned data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vojq.png)

I have tried using `duplicated()` and `drop_duplicates()` on patient numbers to filter out data but that doesn't work in this situation since all patients have received both tests on at least one given date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using 2 group by's and a merge. Comments in the code should help explain what is being done.

```
# get count of # tests for each patient-date combination
grp_df = df.groupby(['PATIENT','DATE'], as_index=False)\
            .agg({'TEST':'count'})\
            .rename(columns = {'TEST':'TEST_CT'})\
            .sort_values(['PATIENT','DATE'])

filt_df = grp_df[grp_df['TEST_CT'] == 2]\ # filter days when patients got both tests only
            .groupby(['PATIENT'], as_index=False)\ 
            .agg({'DATE':'max'}) # get latest date for a patent when both tests were done

op_df = pd.merge(df, filt_df, on = ['PATIENT','DATE']) # filter original data to only include selected patient-date combinations
op_df
```

Comment: Thank you, this got me most of the way there! My data was weird, so I tweaked this to account for (1) some patients had pairs of tests on multiple (different) days and (2) some patients had multiple pairs of tests on one day. So instead of the second groupby (which had the effect of eliminating data I wanted to keep) I used `filt_df = grp_df[grp_df['TEST_CT'] % 2 == 0]` which gave me all patients with all pairs of tests on all days. It did leave one patient who got 2 'A' tests and 0 'B' tests on one day, but that was easy enough to remove manually. Thanks!